# My header buttons are the wrong way round but the right way round in code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm making a website for my IT project. I've made the header but the problem is, the navigation buttons are the wrong way around but they are the right way around in the code.

I've tried rewriting the code but this literally didn't work...

```html
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary justify-content-between navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            Computer Misuse
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="phishing.php">Phishing & Viruses</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="copyright.php">Copyright Law</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="health.php">Health & Safety</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

This is the navigation bar that is included using php's "require_once" method in all of the pages.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dE8f.jpg whenever I click "Copyright Law" it takes me to "Health and Safety" and vice versa but "Phishing & Viruses" works fine.

Anybody have any ideas why this is happening? I am using Bootstrap 4

Comment: You must be doing something differently - because what you are describing is impossible with the code you're showing us, unless you're doing some odd re-directing in either file..

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Your CSS would be relevant here.

Comment: The CSS used is the exact same as what bootstrap supplies with no changes. The full directory used is here and CSS is in a stylesheet href in the HTML files https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K0pXQA3bSJ1iLnElCE1Gb2TnoBVpPjG6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Any chance you have a version online we can see that exhibits the behaviour you claim?

Comment: Please provide us with an https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your href values are flipped. Right-click the link in the nav and click "inspect element" (Chrome). That should show you what the link actually links to. Again: what you're describing just sounds like your link (href) is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, literally didn't see (after I checked over them) that the wrong stuff was in the wrong files so the href was wrong. oof.